# htaccess file www. redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

I have a weird issue

I added the code to htaccess file to redirect any non www to www. but now it takes me to the sub-directory the website files are on

from the DNS cpanel i have pointed the domain directory to /main_web

when i put in throughtheglasseye.org  now it takes to hxxp://www.throughtheglasseye.org/Main_web/ with the error 404 page not found

here is my code -

```
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Disable htaccess view:
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all

# Disable directory browsing:
</Files>
IndexIgnore *
```

im not sure if this is correct please check and let me know what i can do to fix this

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to mod-rewrite.

Rather ask help from your service provider (where cpanel is located).